# Easiest way to replace a substring

Tags: python

What would be the easiest way to replace a substring within a string when I don't know the exact substring I am looking for and only know the delimiting strings?  For example, if I have the following:

```
mystr = 'wordone wordtwo "In quotes"."Another word"'
```

I basically want to delete the first quoted words (including the quotes) and the period (.) following so the resulting string is:

```
'wordone wordtwo "Another word"'
```

Basically I want to delete the first quoted words and the quotes and the following period.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for regular expressions here, using the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

quoted_plus_fullstop = re.compile(r'"[^"]+"\.')
result = quoted_plus_fullstop.sub('', mystr)
```

The pattern matches a literal quote, followed by 1 or more characters that are not quotes, followed by another quote and a full stop.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = 'wordone wordtwo "In quotes"."Another word"'
>>> quoted_plus_fullstop = re.compile(r'"[^"]+"\.')
>>> quoted_plus_fullstop.sub('', mystr)
'wordone wordtwo "Another word"'
```

Comment: Yeah, but it seems python regular expressions work a bit differently and I am no regex expert.  I also tried doing something like the following:  mystr[0:mystr.find('"',1)] + mystr[mystr.find('.',1)+1:]

Comment: @GregH: Regular expressions is the right way to tackle this kind of problems. You don't have to be an expert, start with the regex suggested here and learn why it works. They are very useful, believe me, learning how to express simple patterns will pay off. +1 for this answer.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: So will simple `.find()` calls; nested quotes would require a proper parser in any case.

Comment: @GregH: Using `.find()` can work, if you remember the position of the first quote and use that as a starting point for the second `.find()` call (plus one). Regular expressions do the job here fine though; unless you nest your quotes it is good tool for this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup I know ... I just figured it was worth mentioning when talking about finite autamata and quotes specifically